# Get product info in JSON/XML without authentication

Tags: magento2, products, json

Is it possible to get product info in JSON/XML format without using any authentication from a website using Magento.

For example, Shopify provides product's info as https://mystore/products/product-handle.json for a product available at https://mystore/products/product-handle

Answer (score 1):

I magento2 you can use

```
/V1/products/{sku}
```

You can get more info on [swagger](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/) , look for **catalogProductRepositoryV1**

I would recommend to use some REST Client for this like PostMan , This API usally don't require any Auth unless site owner has made any changes . To get the response in XML pass `Accept  application/xml` in headers